# make: Use grep to look for specific string in all files within a folder

Tags: search, text, makefile, grep

I'd like to look for a specific set of strings in files with a specific file extension (here it's `.textfile`) I have in the current folder. For this, I want to use *make*.

Beforehand, I convert all `.pdf` files to `.txt` files and rename their `.txt` extension to `.textfile`. The filename itself is to be left "unharmed" during the conversion. My code so far:

```
#Variables that save the filenames of all .pdf files
SOURCE=$(wildcard *.pdf)
OBJECT=$(SOURCE:.pdf=.textfile)

#The conversion target
textfile: $(OBJECT)                     
%.textfile: %.pdf
    @pdftotext -f $(FROM_PAGE) $< $@
```

To look for a set of string within these files, I've added this to the code:

```
lookfor-%: $(OBJECT)
    grep -H % $<
```

So calling `make lookfor-Foo` would look for "Foo" in all `.converted` files within the folder. If there is a match, it would print this to stdin:

```
file1.converted: Foo is here
file231.converted: here is Foo for you!
```

However, my Makefile doesn't do this. It always prints out the exact same 2 lines as a "match", even though the set of strings I'm looking for isn't even in any of these lines.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is incorrect.  You need to use the pattern stem `$*` as the search pattern for `grep`...

```
lookfor-%: $(OBJECT)
    grep -H '$*' $<
```

Comment: Wow! It worked, but why? What exactly does '$*' stand for? And why is it quoted?

Comment: `%` is only special in the target/prerequisites of a pattern rule.  It's just a simple character in the recipe.  In the recipe, you have to use automatic variables: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html  The `$*` automatic variable expands to the "stem" (the part that matches the `%` in the target) which is what you want.  The variable is quoted because you're passing its value to the shell and you don't want the shell to interpret special characters (consider if you ran `make 'foo.*bar'`).

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$*` is "The stem with which an implicit rule matches (see How Patterns Match). If the target is dir/a.foo.b and the target pattern is a.%.b then the stem is dir/foo".  The single quotes are just in case the pattern includes any special characters that might be interpreted by the shell -- probably just paranoia on my part :-)